# How to put GroupBoxes next to each other

Tags: c#, winforms

I have dynamically genereted group box with label inside

```
int dlugoscChuja = 0;
string przedmiot = "";//random strings
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
  g.AutoSize = true;
  g.Visible = true;
  g.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        
  var lb = new Label();
  lb.AutoSize = true;
  lb.Location = new Point(6, 16);
  lb.Text = przedmiot;
  g.Controls.Add(lb);
        
  dlugoscChuja += lb.Width;
  if (i != 0)
  {
    g.Location = new Point((i*(g.Width+g.Padding.Size.Width)-100), 12);
  }
  else
  {
    g.Location = new Point(0, 12);
  }
  this.Controls.Add(g); 
}
```

how i can put those group boxes next to each other?

my kod `(i*(g.Width+g.Padding.Size.Width)-100)` of course does not work, is there eany proffesional way to place them? If my labels text is longer of course my group box have more width

Comment: Use a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: You should declare a variables `int x = 0; int pad = 5;` before for loop and then set the location as `g.Location = new Point(x, 12); x = x + g.Width+pad;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Flowlayoutpanel` inside your `groupbox`

We can set the direction of items in `Flowlayoutpanel` to

- TopDown
- LeftToRight
- RightToLeft
- BottomUp

Instead of adding `labels` to `groupBox` add it to `FlowLayoutpanel`

```
//groupbox must outsideloops
GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
g.AutoSize = true;
g.Visible = true;
g.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

var flowPanel;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
flowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
flowPanel.Size = g.Size; // set size of flowpanel to groupbox
flowPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Fill parent size
flowPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;//Use above directions

var lb = new Label();
lb.AutoSize = true;
lb.Location = new Point(6, 16);
lb.Text = przedmiot;


flowPanel.Controls.Add(lb);//lb your labe 

}
g.Controls.Add(flowPanel);//finally add flowpanel to groupbox
this.Controls.Add(g);
```